# JSON get value without using position in array

Tags: json

How do I get the value linked to number inside of properties? I would just use properites[0] but the order of Number and Order Date can sometimes change in my scenario.

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Number",
      "value": "1206327198"
    },
    {
      "name": "Order Date",
      "value": "2018-07-16"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python - loop over the properties and find a match. Once a match is found - stop the loop.

```
data = {
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "Number",
            "value": "1206327198"
        },
        {
            "name": "Order Date",
            "value": "2018-07-16"
        }
    ]
}
for prop in data['properties']:
    if prop.get('name') == 'Number':
        print(prop.get('value'))
        break
```

output

```
1206327198
```